# PHPDOC2 OUTPUT NOT PRODUCE

Tags: phpdoc

After installed the phpdoc. I have run the

`phpdoc run -h`

it gave the output. But when  run the 
`phpdoc run  -d . -t ouput` 
not produce any output.Any changes need to do please suggest me.
Thanks In advance

Answer (score 0):

Verify that you at least have some *.php files in that same "." source directory.